# How to fix, "FoxQZ2.java:39: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown" this error message in jGRASP?

Tags: java, jgrasp

Here is my code: Instructions:
Please name your .java file as: YourLastNameQZ2.java
Please develop a Java program to count the number of digit characters in a 
text file (This program generates only one line of output)(A digit character 
is in the range of 0 to 9)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FoxQZ2 
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      //Initilazing 
      int charCount = 0;
      int wordCount = 0;
      int lineCount = 0;
      BufferedReader reader = null;
      try
      {
         //Reading the text file
         reader = new BufferedReader(new
FileReader("C:/Users/cmf8398/Documents/CIS 201/FoxQZ2.java"));

         //Read lines in file
         String line = reader.readLine();
         while( line != null)
         {
            //Update lineCount every time we read line
            lineCount++;

            //Counting words by space on line
            String[] words = line.split(" ");

            //Update wordCount by how many words in the line
            wordCount = wordCount + words.length;

           //Update charCount by iterating through words on the line
           for(String word: words)
           {
            charCount = charCount + word.length();
           }

           //Read next line
           line = reader.readLine();
         }
         //Output
         System.out.print("Number of Characters in file: "+ charCount);
         System.out.print("Number of Words in file: "+ wordCount);
         System.out.print("Number of lines in file: "+ lineCount);
      }  
      finally
        {
            try
            {
                reader.close();           //Closing the reader
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: When I run this code I get this message: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: And I added some code to the initializing part  for:                           
charCount = >=0 && <=9; For the range of characters from 0 to 9.